# When asking for a Range input : object variable or with block variable not set in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want user to input the cell Range

```
Dim FromRang, ToRang As Range

'Ask the user to input the cell Range in which to search for the sub strings
FromRang = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Search Range From:", Type:=8)
ToRang = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Search Range To:", Type:=8)
```

But this is giving me an error: "object variable or with block variable not set in excel vba"

Comment: **Set** FromRang = input.

Comment: I would probably declare two string variables and capture the text that the user inputs as the Range argument. There are controls available to return a range object but I don't think that InputBox is one of them.

Comment: @mehow can you please be a little clear. Am new to excel vba.

Comment: @Marshall Can you please tell me which controls I can use to return a range object

Comment: The control is called a 'RefEdit' control but I think you are better off using the InputBox method that you have started with- sorry opened my mouth a little too soon...

Comment: @Marshall But it is giving me the above error when trying to use.

Comment: See mehow's comment: Set FromRang = Application.InputBox...etc

Comment: Thank you both.. This worked Dim FromRang, ToRang As Range

    'Ask the user to input the cell Range in which to search for the sub strings
    Set FromRang = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Search Range From:", Type:=8)
    Set ToRang = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Search Range To:", Type:=8)

Comment: Note that `Dim FromRang, ToRang As Range` only declares `ToRang` as a `Range`. `FromRang` is declared as a `Variant`, by default. To declare them both as ranges do: `Dim FromRang as Range, ToRang As Range`. Take a look at [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx). Scroll down to "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects such as a `Range` can only be assigned in VBA by using Set. So as mehow mentioned you should use:

```
Set FromRang = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Search Range From:", Type:=8)
```

Furthermore dimensioning multiple variables requires you to state the type for every variable separately:

```
Dim FromRang As Range, ToRang As Range
```

Otherwise the first one will be unspecified and by default this results in it becoming of the type `Variant` which could lead to undesired behaviour.

Comment: +1. I didnt know of `Application.InputBox` and `Type` parameter when compared to regular VB `InputBox` function. Thanks.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say `FromRang` is declared as a `Variant`.

Comment: @DougGlancy I was doubting as to do so, let me improve it such